# Is spree-2.1 recommended for production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree

Recently I have upgraded my spree application from spree-1.1 to 2.1.

But here, I am getting the errors when I am running the app in production mode.

Could you please let me know your comments.

Is spree-2.1 + rails-4 will recommended for production  officially ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Spree v. 2.1 has been officially released on September 16th ([more info here](http://spreecommerce.com/blog/spree-2-1-0-released)), so you can freely use it in any production environment.

If you are getting errors you should focus on the migration process from v. 1.1 to 2.1 (there's quite a big gap there).